# Spotfire Drop Down list in text area can filter other drop down list

Tags: javascript, ironpython, spotfire

I want to know if drop down list in text area (action control) can filter other drop down list.
 for example, i have a drop down list of Month, family and model. if i choose Month of october, the list of family and model drop down list will show only family and model that belong to the month of october. same also family dropdown, if i choose milk the model will show only those coming from milk.

when trigger the drop down the visualization (details) should also change the data based on the filters.

Thanks you in advance!

[image: Spotfire Dashboard]